# g++ insist to use std::string rather than string

Tags: c++, namespaces, g++, std

I wrote a simple program like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
   string a;
   std::cin >> a;
   std::cout << a << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

It failed to compiled and the compiler suggest me to use `std::string` instead of `string`.
After using `std::string`, everything is fine.

My question is why my program needs to use `std::string` in order to be compiler successfully ?

Comment: `using namespace std`

Comment: because string is the class provided by standard and it has been defined under std namespace.Hence compiler gives the error.

Comment: put a `using namespace std` before the use of string will allow you to use the std::string class without the namespace prefix.

Comment: The program is in the global namespace.  If you want to access something in a namespace you prefix it.  Or you can put `using namespace std;` just after the includes - although you might not want to pull everything in std into your program.

Comment: For the same reason you needed the `std::` namespace resolution  for *everything else in this program* (`cin`, `endl`, `cout`).

Comment: `using std::string;` is a safer idea than `using namespace std;`.  The latter gets you hundreds of things, some of which might have unexpected side effects.

Comment: If you do it in main, you're pretty safe, it is when people put it in the global scope it becomes an issue with other libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string` class is in the namespace `std`.  You can remove the scoping for `std::`.

You'd do best to include it inside the main function, so names don't colide if you use a library that uses the name string or `cout`, or such.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  string a;
  cin >> a;
  cout << a << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`string` is in `std` namespace, it's only valid to use `std::string` rather than `string` (the same for `std::cin`, `std::vector` etc). However, in practice, some compilers may let a program using `string` etc without `std::` prefix compile, which makes some programmers think it's OK to omit `std::`, but it's not in standard C++.

So it's best to use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
   std::string a;
   std::cin >> a;
   std::cout << a << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Note that it's NOT a good idea to use `using namespace std;` (though it's legal), especially NOT put it in a header.

If you are tired of typing all the `std::`, declare all the names with namespace you **use** is one option:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
   string a;
   cin >> a;
   cout << a << endl;
   return 0;
}
```